# Firebug Lite mobile

Tags: browser, bookmarklet, firebug-lite

I'd like to install Firebug Lite mobile. I'm following the instructions on this [site](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite_mobile). Unfortunately when I execute attached bookmarklet JavaScript code I get errors like that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
    at data:text/html,<script>(function(){ var fb = document.createElement('script'); fb.type = 'text/javascript'; fb.src = 'https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js:1:197
    at data:text/html,<script>(function(){ var fb = document.createElement('script'); fb.type = 'text/javascript'; fb.src = 'https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js:1:217
```

Anyone got it working?

Comment: Firebug Lite is not maintained for many years now, so it's no wonder that it doesn't work as expected anymore.